# Typo3 Instance Exception

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

Why i'm getting this Exception?

> Argument 1 passed to KRT\KrtJobs\Domain\Model\Jobs::setPlaces() must
>   be an instance of KRT\KrtJobs\Domain\Model\Places, string given,
>   called in
>   /var/www/html/Newwebsite/typo3conf/ext/krt_jobs/Classes/Controller/JobsController.php
>   on line 96

**This is my code in the controller**

```
if($arguments['jobSave']){
        $addJobsInfo = GeneralUtility::makeInstance('KRT\\krtJobs\\Domain\\Model\\Jobs'); 
        $addJobsInfo->setJobtitle($arguments['jobDesignation']);
        $addJobsInfo->setCompany($arguments['jobCompany']);
        $addJobsInfo->setPlaces($arguments['jobPlace']);
        $this->jobsRepository->add($addJobsInfo);
        $persistenceManager = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\PersistenceManager');
        $persistenceManager->persistAll();
    }
```

**This is my Model**

```
/**
 * Sets the Places
 *
 * @param \KRT\krtJobs\Domain\Model\Places $places
 * @return void
 */
public function setPlaces(\KRT\krtJobs\Domain\Model\Places $places)
{
    $this->places = $places;
}
```

**I'm Getting error on this**

> $addJobsInfo->setPlaces($arguments['jobPlace']);

I want to insert the data into jobs Database but the places are called from another table. So when I'm trying to insert I'm getting the above exception.

**I'm using typo3 version 7**

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load an Instance of Places and set this, error says you cant set strings.

```
$places = $this->placesRepository->findByName($arguments['jobPlace']);
$job->setPlaces($places):
```

or something like this... and you should always use Domain Models in singular eg. "Place".

Comment: That's working, thank you. Thank you for the suggestion, I will keep this in mind for future extensions.